# What is the keystore used to sign JWT tokens in WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I have chosen to make my access tokens JWT's by selecting the JWT radio button in my service provider's application settings.

[image]

I am interested in knowing what the keystore used to sign these JWT tokens is so I can decode them.  Is it the "Keystore" referenced in carbon.xml or another keystore?  By default that value is wso2carbon.jks.

Keystore in carbon.xml

```
<Security>
    <!--
        KeyStore which will be used for encrypting/decrypting passwords
        and other sensitive information.
    -->
    <KeyStore>
        <!-- Keystore file location-->
        <Location>...</Location>
        <!-- Keystore type (JKS/PKCS12 etc.)-->
        <Type>...</Type>
        <!-- Keystore password-->
        <Password>...</Password>
        <!-- Private Key alias-->
        <KeyAlias>...</KeyAlias>
        <!-- Private Key password-->
        <KeyPassword>...</KeyPassword>
    </KeyStore>
```

I understand that a JWKS endpoint is exposed at `oauth/jwks` as well.  I assume that the same keystore is used to sign the tokens and represent the JWK data, where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed.  It is the `<keystore>` referenced in carbon.xml

Answer (score 0):

By default "wso2carbon.jks" is used to sign JWT tokens. If you only needs to decode the token you can do it from [here](https://jwt.io/#debugger). You will need the public key of the default keystore if you need to verify the signature of the jwt token. For this you can refer [JWT Token Generation doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/JWT+Token+Generation).